# Filtering database outputs rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a little lost on this, so I have the activity feeds gem and the devise gem.

I want to have the ability to list all the posts made by a specified user

Controller

```
 def userstory
 @userstory = Story.where(params[:user_id])
 end
```

View

```
<% @userstories = Story.where(:user_ud) %>

<% @userstories.each do |story| %>
```

I also think my routes are wrong

```
 match '/stories/userstory/:user_id',     to: 'stories#userstory',       via: 'get'
resources :stories, :only =>[:show]
```

Comment: Try with Story.where(user_id: params[:user_id])

Comment: Which Rails version?

Comment: current rails, and does params[:user_id] need to be defined in controller?

Comment: Use `Story.find(params[:user_id])` or `Story.where(user_id: params[:user_id])`.

Comment: And yes, as I see you're doing it in your view, try to define the `@stories` in your current method, and then access to it within your view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to ensure that `stories` has a `user_id` column pointing to `users`. Second, you need to properly define associations:

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stories
end
```

Then in your controller add:

```
# I'm assuming this is index on a controller.
def index
  @stories = current_user.stories
end
```

You should be able to reference `@stories` in a view:

```
<%= @stories.each do |story| %>
  <!-- RENDER story HERE -->
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you handle params in Rails with forms, if you don't perform such action (fill a form, send it) you won't be able to deal with them. If you try to print in your view the current value of your `params[:user_id]` maybe you'll get `nil`, that's why when you try to `find` a Story through the `id` which in this case is `nil` then you get some response.

Try specifying your `@stories` within your controller and in the corresponding method and then use it in your view, maybe like:

```
# app/controllers/stories_controller.rb
def some_method
  @stories = Story.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
  ...
```

Just to mention, as far as I know, all the dynamic methods except for find_by_... and find_by_...! are deprecated since the Rails 4 version, so maybe you'd like to use `find_by` or `where` instead (see [reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations)).

Seeing your routes then I assume you're in '/stories/userstory/id' in your navigator, and you click on some story to show it, then you need to use the method `show` in your `StoriesController` and this way to find such story through the `params[:user_id]`.

Comment: Also how do I call this method in my view?

Comment: Can you add your controller and view?

Comment: correct that is what I am attempting, the idea is when I am viewing a user's profile I can see the post history of that user

Comment: So you need to declare the `@userstories` in the `show` method on the `UsersController`, something like `def show; @user = User.find(params[:id]); @userstories = Story.where('user_id = ?', @user.id); end`

Comment: I can declare two different functions in a single method?

Comment: oh wait, in the usercontroller, not the stories controller

Comment: Do you mean two variables?

Comment: so the @userstories method is in the storycontroller? And how do I pass the value in my view?

Comment: The current controller, which responds to the route you're, assign both values, and then they'll be able to be used within your view.

Comment: Okay, well what is the syntax for calling it during view? Is it Story.userstory or something that?

Comment: Just your `@userstories` variable within your views.

Comment: I get am undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
It is reaching the userstory in the controller though, that's a huge benifit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143110/discussion-between-sebastian-palma-and-jay).